# How to get the the current number of row using mouseover in JQgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, row

I want to get the number of row by mouseover. This is my code :

```
    gridComplete: function() {
                var myGrid = $('#list2'),
                x = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
//here I get the total number of rows in jqgrid


                $('#list2 #popupData').mouseover(function(e) {
                    //here I dont know what to write and i how to get the current row number, not the ID 
                });
            },
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

This will work, in general, though i imagine it would not behave well with paging enabled.

```
    beforeSelectRow:function(rowid,e) 
    {
    alert("Row [" + rowid + "] is row number [" + $("#" + rowid)[0].rowIndex + "]");
        return false;
    },
```

But the exact code would depend on what #popupData is.  are you trying to find the row number of the selected row ?

UPDATE: per discussion in comments, this is how it can be handled , changing the alert for whatever display mechanism you want

```
$("#popupdata").mouseover(function() {
     alert( $(this).parents('tr')[0].rowIndex);
});
```

Comment: #poppupdata represents  a div tag in a particula cell. i want to make a mouserover event on the content of that div. Now with your example, I have to do a click on the item before the mouseover event will work. Thx

Comment: Wouldn't this be better to handle in your backend code ? as you iterate through the rows, keep a counter. then you can use something like
<div id='popupdata' title='$rownum'></div>

If you want to do this via jqgrid though, i think this will work in loadcomplete
$("#popupdata").mouseover(function() {
alert( $(this).parents('tr')[0].rowIndex);
});

Comment: finnally i figured it out , as you said in comment(keep a counter), but I expected better solution

Comment: the updated code i added to my answer wont work for you ?
Unsure what a better solution would be here as throwing a popup to show the row number is an odd requirement